# drop event for repeating divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a div which will be repeating

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    <div class="preview"><img src="path"/></div>
}
```

I want to have drop event for all these div, if drop from one div to another it should alert me.

I tried this one but didn't worked.

```
$('.preview').on('drop', function (e) {
    alert("dropped")
    console.log("e", e);
});
```

What should I do to have drop event for all divs?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0xjwqkqo/1)

please try to drag the image into the div (vishnu)

Comment: Also make sure that you are waiting to the `$(document).ready(function(){ /code here  });` or load or even `$(function() { //code here });` Its unclear the "didn't work" but can you share a snipped/jsfiddle or link to test it out?

Comment: Is there any error messages?

Comment: I have added a plunker.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear, but if your elements are dynamic you could add the event listener to the document with the selector like this.

```
$(document).on('drop', '.preview', function (e) {
    alert("dropped")
    console.log("e", e);
});
```

[jQuery on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)

Also note, make sure your code is in a ready handler, like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('drop', '.preview', function (e) {
        alert("dropped")
        console.log("e", e);
    });
});
```

Comment: it didn't work, please check the demo link I provided

Comment: @vishnuprasadkv in your demo you have `id` not `class` and jsfiddle is setup incorrectly, see this update: http://jsfiddle.net/0xjwqkqo/2/ also I have change the event for click as you have no drag and drop features